# Window properties without window

Tags: javascript

Recently I noticed usage of "`event`" variable in the function where neither parameters nor closure contains it.
But it works and event is present. It looks like "`event`" refers to window.event.

Therefore 2 questions:

1. Why can I access window properties just as variables without referencing to window?
2. What event is located in default "`event`" variable if we are in usual JavaScript(in my case TypeScript) code, not in handler or anything that gets event as a parameter?

Explanation about event vs window event:
If to type directly in devTools console "window.innerHeight" - we will get the number. The same result we can get just typing "innerHeight" without "window".

Comment: Please provide some example code. I am not 100% sure what you are asking here.

Comment: 1. [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window): _"A global variable, `window`, representing the window in which the script is running, is exposed to JavaScript code."_, 2. [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event): _"The read-only Window property event returns the Event which is currently being handled by the site's code. Outside the context of an event handler, the value is always undefined. You should avoid using this property in new code, and should instead use the Event passed into the event handler function."_

Comment: it can explain why I get event on window - some another handler might be executing in this time and waiting for response.
The question remains about window properties. I've described once more in the bottom of the question.

Comment: You can specify any of the window properties or methods this way because `window` represents the global scope. As you mentioned you can do it with `innerHeight` but you can also access HTML tag ids `<div id="one">` as  `window.one` or `one`. Note that this is only true in web browsers and not other JS environments like Node.

Comment: It looks as an answer. I've always used window in such cases and didn't know there was other way. It might be bad practice to use window properties directly in global scope.

Comment: When you write `window`, you’re accessing the `”window”` property of the global scope. This property is itself a reference to the global scope, which is why `event`, `window.event`, `window.window.event`, `window.window.window.event`, etc. all refer to the same thing. This is simply how Javascript was designed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Why can I access window properties just as variables without referencing to window?

"Why?" questions aren't really answerable without asking the people that wrote the specification. This is just how the `window` object works because it represents the global scope. As I mentioned in my comment, you can access any global property either with or without the `window.` prefix. That's because global variables are actually attached to the global object, in this case `window` -- nothing can be outside of this global scope. Again, this is not true in other JS environments where there is no `window` object, e.g. in Node the global object is named `global`.

---

2. What event is located in default "event" variable if we are in usual JavaScript(in my case TypeScript) code, not in handler or anything that gets event as a parameter?

You can log it for yourself and see:

```js
console.log(window.event);

button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  console.log(window.event);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me!</button>
```

According to the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), references to `window.event` outside of a function handling the event are `undefined`. You can see from the snippet that the first call is in fact `undefined` while the second inside the event listener logs the event being handled.